# Binary operator expected? Don't understand

Tags: unix

Writing simple bash script to read through files in directory and print file names and sizes of those under 100bytes and those over 1000bytes.

```
#!/bin/bash

Maxsize=1000
Minsize=100
FSite=$(ls $dir) 
for file in $FSite; 
    do Size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
    if [ -f "$file" ] && [ "$Size" -lt $Minsize ] 
       then [ wc -c "$file" ]; # Then print out its byte count
    fi
done
```

Comment: Did you look at `find . -size ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the script
Could you try to delete square brackets around
 `then  wc -c "$file"`